# socket.io + heroku port issue

Tags: heroku, socket.io, ionic-framework

I'm running socket.io 1.0 in a node.js app on heroku. I'm talking to my server through an ionic/angular app that I'm running locally on `http://localhost:9107`

In my app I'm loading socket.io in the front end like this:

```
<script src="https://myapp.herokuapp.com/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

This loads up fine, but then my app starts throwing errors in the console:

```
https://myapp.herokuapp.com:9107/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1413741961075-13 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Notice the port number 9107 I'm using to run my ionic app locally in the browser being used in the socket request later on. I have no clue why socket.io is doing this or how I can get rid of that port in there.

Does anyone know why this happens and how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This took me a while to figure out but the solution was simple: I manually added the port :443 to my socket connection and that seems to override the behaviour mentioned above!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set a port on socket.io client, just use your heroku app url on socketio connection.